# Added Windows firewall rule to block IP, but ping still works

Tags: ip, blocking, windows-firewall, netsh

I wanted to block all in/out connections to a remote IP using `netsh`:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OUT RULE" dir=out interface=any action=block remoteip=<remoteIP>/32
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IN RULE" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=<remoteIP>/32
```

But now the `ping <remoteIP>` still works.

I want to achieve something similar to the following Linux commands:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <remoteIP> -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -d <remoteIP> -j DROP
```

How can block that IP in Windows?

Comment: Do you know in which order your firewall rules apply? If the "allow ping" rule applies before the "block" one, the ping will still work. This is the same as having `-p icmp -j ACCEPT` before `-s badip -j DROP` in your iptables.

Comment: I don't know in which order they are applied, but they are the first one based on the alphabetical order. Can I increase somehow their priority to overwrite all other rules?

Comment: What type of traffic are you blocking? TCP, UDP or ICMP? A ping is an ICMP

Comment: If I don't specify a protocol, I'm expecting to block everything.

Answer (score 2):

A command to block ICMP protocol:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Disable Ping" dir=out action=block protocol=icmpv4
```

and the same thing but for `icmpv6`. 
Reply shall be “OK”. 
And when you try to ping again, reply shall be “General Failure”.